# Prononciation de l'ancien français

Tags: prononciation, ressources, ancien-français, ipa

Je cherche des ressources qui donneraient la prononciation des mots d'ancien français, par exemple, sous forme d'IPA.

Je sais que l'ancien français a une prononciation relativement phonétique, mais je n'ai pas trouvé une telle base de données.

Cela permettrait de constater l'évolution de la prononciation des mots français, et comprendre l'évolution des graphies ou les graphies alternatives.

(En bonus, si vous avez de bons dictionnaires d'ancien français en ligne, je suis aussi preneuse. J'ai beaucoup de mal à retracer l'évolution à partir du latin de certains mots.)

Comment: Pour la demande sur des dictionnaires d'ancien français en ligne, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait mieux que ce qui se trouve sur [Dicfro](http://micmap.org/dicfro/dictionaries) déjà cités sur ce site.

Comment: Merci pour le lien: Ils ont le Gaffiot et le Cange que j'utilise déjà, mais je n'ai pas trouvé d'IPA de l'ancien français. Pour les ressources pour l'ancien français, il y a beaucoup de ressources qui ne sont plus en ligne, je n'ai pas trouvé de prononciation. Je pense que cela ne doit pas exister, mais même si la prononciation était régulière, elle a tout de même évolué et connu des variations régionales.

Comment: Par exemple "le couronnement de Louis", me renvoie sur la page wikipédia, mais pas sur le texte. Il n'y a pas de glossaire. Pareil pour d'autres liens, en fait, c'est plus une présentation du texte, une notice, qu'une accessibilité de la ressource en ligne. ça peut aussi sûrement être recherché ailleurs, je vais essayer, mais ce n'est pas disponible sur le site. Pour le lexique de Godefroy, seules 2 pages sont disponibles.

Comment: Effectivement le "bonus", c'est juste "dictionnaire de l'ancien français", mais je n'ai pas trouvé sur ce site, bien que ce site soit très intéressant à consulter.

Comment: *Glossaire du Couronnement de Louis*  52 pages (numérotées de  173 à 225). 
*Dictionnaire de Godefroy* et avec son complément : 8 000 pages, 160 000 entrées répartis en 10 volumes. 
Lexique de Godefroy 550 pages, 55 000 entrées.
etc....
Pour tous les ouvrages on peut entrer un mot, une lettre, ou le n° de la page au choix. Toutes les pages sont visibles, pour le défilement page par page on clique sur les flèches, « gauche » ou « droite », selon. Absolument [tout ce qui est annoncé](http://micmap.org/dicfro/dictionaries) est disponible.

Comment: Le *dictionnaire de Godefroy* est aussi accessible sur *Gallica* mais j'y trouve la recherche moins aisée bien que pour certains volumes l'ocr soit terminée (pas tous il me semble).

Answer (score 2):

Pour comprendre l'évolution de la prononciation des mots français, je conseillerais tout de même, pour ne pas réinventer la roue, de consulter aussi l'un des manuels de phonétique historique du français disponibles sur le marché du livre (Gaston Zink, Emile Bourciez etc.).